# Migrate Drupal7 to local, user login link redirect to live, how to redirect it to local?

Tags: users, uri

I have changed cookies name and base URL for my local environment, I have also emptied all cache tables, but still it redirects to the live site.

Like `http://server1/mysitename/user` to `https://www.mysitename/user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found my answer... by google search.. :)

```
UPDATE variable SET value = 's:1:"0";' WHERE name = 'securepages_enable';
```

pass this query in db and flush all cache.. :)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is your using the secure login module.

Either:

```
drush vset securelogin_base_url "http://server1/mysitename/user"
```

or

```
drush dis securelogin
```

Comment: hey I'm new in drupal.. i think drush is command line argument, and I dont know how its work.. is any different way,??

Comment: Yes drush is a command line tool for Drupal, my second command does pretty much the same as your answer below.  Glad you got the problem solved.